# How to create a custom callback function in cakephp after saveAll()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I am developing an application in cakephp. In this application I am using saveAll() function at many different places to save multiple records. What is need is to create a callback function which automatically gets called after saveAll() is executed, as I think there is no predefined callback function in cakephp which gets called after saveAll(). I know there is a function afterSave(), which gets called after every save() action. What can be the solution. Any suggestions would really be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: I think afertSave() http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/es/view/1053/afterSave function is your best chance.

Comment: but the problem is that afterSave() gets called after every single row is saved. So cant use it.

Comment: Redefine saveAll function in your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the saveAll function in your model as follows:

```
function saveAll($datos=null, $opciones = array()){
    parent::saveAll($datos, $opciones);
    $this->yourCallBackFunction();
}

function yourCallBackFunction(){
    //do something
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

```
public function saveAll($data, $options) {
    $return = parent::saveAll($data, $options);

    // your callback code here

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: thanx alot.. i should just place this function in app_model right..?

Comment: Yes, AppModel or a specific model, depending on what you want.